# Wordpress Custom Post and Taxonomy 404

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm building an FAQ section on a wordpress site. I have a custom post type called faq and that has a custom taxonomy called faq-category. I'm also using a plugin called `Custom Post Type Permalinks`.

I'm trying to achieve the following permalink structure:

- domain.com/faq
- domain.com/faq/category
- domain.com/faq/category/question-title

So far I can only seem to get 2/3 working. So the example below gives me:

- domain.com/faq
- domain.com/faq/category

and a `404` on `domain.com/faq/category/question-title

If i change: `'slug' => 'faq'` to `'slug' => ''` on the custom taxonomy i re-write. I get the `404` error on the taxonomy page and the single post will work.

Thanks

```
/**
 * Custom taxonomys
 */
function create_faq_tax() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'faq-category',
        'faq',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faq', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true ),
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_faq_tax' );


/**
 * FAQ Custom post type
 */
function create_faq_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'faq',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'FAQ\'s' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'FAQ' ),
                'add_new' => 'Add new FAQ',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add a new FAQ',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit FAQ',
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('faq-category'),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-feedback',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'faq', 'with_front' => false ),
            'query_var' => true,
        )
    );


}
add_action( 'init', 'create_faq_post_type' );
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with my own custom post type (beer) and a similar taxonomy (beer/style). If I set the slug to `beer/style` it throws a 404, but if I set the slug to `style` the tax page works, albeit not in my desired permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

After you create new Custom Post Type or Taxonomy you will have to regenerate your permalinks: **wp-admin/options-permalink.php**. Push the "Save changes" button

Comment: Did you try to generate custom post type here (https://generatewp.com/post-type/)?

Comment: So the problem seems to be that I want to use the same permalink /faq